# Hard drive won't work after deleting whole partitions

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystem-corruption

I was trying to install Ubuntu server to my external SSD via a bootable USB flash drive. After deleting whole partitions in the disk I changed my decision to boot Ubuntu and cancelled the installation.

Now when I connect hard drive it shows "Incorrect Function" in Windows. Other that that it won't show up in any other tools like gparted.

It showed up in BIOS menu as connected but I cannot access it from anywhere.

Comment: "to my external SSD", "when I connect hard drive" – SSD is not a "hard drive", so are are referring to *two* different devices? I mean: you tried to install Ubuntu Server to your SSD and this act somehow affected another device, the hard drive; right?

Comment: I tried to install it on my external hard drive. It is a SSD. Both are the same sorry for using two words

Comment: Sounds like you FUBAR'd your partition table. You can "re-initialise" (AKA create a new partition table) and it should work again

Answer (score 2):

1. Plug in the SSD.
2. Open a drive management tool, e.g.,

   - Ubuntu *Disks*
   - Windows *diskmgmt.msc*
   - Third party tool, such as *DiskGenius*
3. Remove *all* partitions *on the correct drive*.
4. Some tools ask you to "Save all" or "Commit" that operation -- do so.
5. Assuming you want to use that SSD as removable media, create a *single* partition.
6. Commit, if needed.
7. Format that partition as desired, e.g.,

   - NTFS for mostly Windows and Linux usage
   - ext4 for Linux-only usage.
8. Commit, if needed.

That drive should now be recognized.

Comment: I tried Ubuntu disks. It shows my external hard drive but I can't access anything and it won't show a partitioning scheme at least. It shows my external hard in windows disk management tools also but i cant do anything. Disk Genius couldn't detect the external hard drive at least

Comment: The drive may be dead. Look to the drive manufacturer's site for tools to fix it -- though don't be too hopeful.